# How to adjust UIBarButtonItem text size in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I have a uibarbuttonitem with a back arrow created from a character code.  In iOS4.3 and lower, the arrow looks ok however in iOS5, it shows up much smaller.  Has anyone seen this?  Any idea how to fix it other than using an actual image?

```
    // flex space
    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    // back
    unichar backArrowCode = 0x25C0; //BLACK LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE
    NSString *backArrowString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&backArrowCode length:1];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:backArrowString 
                                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                         target:self 
                                                                         action:@selector(webViewGoBack:)];        

    [backBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];

    // add
    self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:backBarButtonItem, flex, nil];

    if (self.navigationController != nil) {
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
        [self.navigationController.toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor colorForToolBar]];
    }
    [backBarButtonItem release];
    [flex release];
```

[image: example buttons]

Comment: I think that's because in iOS 5 you have Emoji keyboard support built-it and the char you've provided is an Emoji char, I recommend you to use an UIImage instead of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guy Dor!  Your comment was correct. I've switched back to using a UIImage.